# Having strange CSS issue

Tags: html, css

I made some mini plugin which works with Youtube API.

But something wrong with my CSS: It destroys whole page structure.

Here is the main page where all works well (without problematic piece of CSS):

http://pikproduction.az/?lang=ru

and the page that I'm talking about (witH problematic piece of CSS):

http://pikproduction.az/?lang=ru&page=11

The same CSS working well on another page

http://tural.us/?page=utube

Can't figure out, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding your "video" class to video wrapper and I don't know why but html tag too. It has width:228px; that causes problem. Also i'm not sure why are you using classes on your html tag(and there are like 20+). Solution for your problem is rename video class or delete it from html tag. Good solution is change your html tag to `<html lang="ru" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Comment: " "video" class to video wrapper and ***I don't know why but html tag too.***" -  Don't understand what are you talking about http://screencast.com/t/GhbDlBNBi  Where is class="video" in HTML tag?

Comment: When i check your page with firebug, i saw that your html tag uses "video" class for styling. Didn't look diretcly to source but some typo in html or jquery selector issue or css typo may cause this. I will check your codes again.

Comment: Please say me line number or screenshot where have you found .video in html tag? Here is what I see screencast.com/t/GhbDlBNBi

Comment: Ah. I'm using modernizr. Maybe it's related with this?

Comment: I don't know may be, I'm still looking.But now i suggest you to download firebug and use for debugging, styling while you are looking at page. http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Ok. fixed problem by renamning class. Refresh the page. Pls see `video-view-count` and `video-time` spans. Why they located not in right places?

Comment: Because your video container(video class) has more height then video thumbnail, and you are using bottom:2px; for your video-view-count. And that video-view-count is child of video containter not video thumbnail. So it's using bottom:2px; according to video container. Solution is move your video-view-count to video thumbnail or (first one is better but if you dont want to use that)use bottom:12px;. More comments here will be bad since we got solution for your question. If you have another issues that doesnt worth for creating new question. Go for chat. I will be there for a while.

Answer (score 1):

the whole .video class from your  tag should be removed on problematic page:

```
.video {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
    width: 228px;
}
```

Comment: It solves page structure problem but video class is for video thumbnails. I can't show thumbs without this class. What's your solution for this problem?

Comment: it should not be in <html> tag - use it where the video thumbnails are used

Comment: Please say me line number or screenshot where have you found .video in html tag? Here is what I see http://screencast.com/t/GhbDlBNBi

Comment: If you use firebug you will see all styles are in <html class=" .... fontface video audio localstorage..." - something to do with Modernizr

Comment: Ah. I'm using modernizr. Maybe it's related with this?

Comment: Ok. fixed problem by renamning class. Refresh the page. Pls see `video-view-count` and `video-time` spans. Why they located not in right places?

Comment: remove right:2px and vertical-align:top from .video-time .video-view-count classes